# What is the eVisa site for Turkey? (2023)

Tags: turkey, e-visas

I found [this site](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/) but the nature of the site makes me question its authenticity. Could someone confirm if this is the correct one with a reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is indeed the official website for applying for a Turkey eVisa - https://www.evisa.gov.tr/

Comment: this is correct but maybe you could explain your reasoning?

Comment: @mlc Much the same as my reasoning for calling water wet, because I know it to be true!

Comment: [.]gov[.]tr does kind of give it away...